# Starting up Roo Shell leads to lucene error

Tags: lucene, spring-roo

Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> Lexical error at line 21, column 39.  Encountered: "\u2013" (8211), after : ""

How to restore the index?

now, when I upgrade to Roo 1.2.1 the error message is gone but I get `roo> null` with the same effect: no *.aj sources are generated and woven.

The code is fine, I've checked it out on two other different machines where all .aj were generated, no error message.

Hypothesis 1: it has to do with windos/ linux character interpetation. On Linux it worked, under Windows error

Comment: I have exactly the same problemma. This error occurred during the transition to Roo 1.2.0. Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> Lexical error at line 3, column 27. Encountered: "\u2013" (8211), after : ""

Comment: @Denis Have you checked out a Project that is also developed on Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the mystery.

In one of the tests I declare **a german constant with 'umlaute': ö is the culprit not en-dash.**

So the parser for aspect generation reads this and can't cope with it. It's a bug IMHO, especially I hate the fact that the exception can't tell which sequence of characters is surounding the culprit. That would really kill debugging time.

Interestingly on Linux no problems.